# OpenGL: Draw lines with VBO

Tags: opengl, lines, vbo

How to draw several separate lines using a single VBO?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`glDrawElements(GL_LINES, ..., ..., ...);`

Comment: Yup. There really is nothing else to it. This is the right answer. Each pair of points form one line. So, you can store unlimited lines in one huge VBO.

Answer (score 8):

In OpenGL-3.1 and later there's a functionality called *primitive restart*. It works by specifying a special vertex array element index that causes the current primitive to be restarted. That way a single element array allows to draw several GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_QUAD_STRIP.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xml

This is largely based on the NV_primitive_restart extension: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/primitive_restart.txt

Apart from that you can use a primitive type in which vertices are not shared and blow up the element index array a bit.

Comment: glDrawElements should be enough - plus as you say primative restart is not available in all versions.